# How to align text fields in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align text fields in a div and make them float left so that they look like a table.

I want a layout like below:

```
Label1: TextField    Label2: TextField     Label3: TextField
Label4: TextField    Label5: TextField     Label6: TextField
```

I tried to do this but it just won't come out correct.  http://jsbin.com/izuwi3/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put this together really quickly, so it can definitely be improved upon, but how about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LBcp5/1/

What I'm doing is essentially creating a container for what would be a row in a table. The way I'm doing this is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
   // put whatever you want in here
</div>
```

... and I'm styling this `row` class with `clear: both` so that each row will be on its own line. You can add `<div>` elements within each row, as many as you want, and floating them to the left or using `display: inline` to get the effect you want.

So when you want multiple rows, you create multiple of these `row` containers. Check out the jsFiddle demo above for an example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: problem I am having is when adding a button in the end. When I add a button in the end it should be in the next line.  However, it just floats with the second row..

Comment: If I add a button in the bottom of second row then it should become a third row with button in the middle somewhere.  However, now if I add a new div for button ..it just floats on the second row

Comment: ah I understand... you want to use `<div class="clear"></div>` to clear the floats, so then it would go on a third row

Comment: @reeth... I just did an update to my response. Instead of using the `<div class="clear"></div>` to separate rows, I created wrappers that each have a clearing style. Check out the demo.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Fppsq/)?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label1">Label1</label>
            <input name="label1" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label4">Label4</label>
            <input name="label4" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label2">Label2</label>
            <input name="label2" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label5">Label5</label>
            <input name="label5" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label3">Label3</label>
            <input name="label3" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="label-container">
            <label for="label6">Label6</label>
            <input name="label6" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 800px;
}

#left,
#center,
#right
{
    float: left;
}

.label-container
{
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can for example put each column in a `fieldset` tag, set it's `display` attribute to **block**, `float` to **left** and set `width` to desired value.

i think it'll allways end using some tag like span or div to group those fields, however the fieldset tag is the most desired one cause it's invented exactly for grouping form fields :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField1">Label1:</label>
        <input id="TextField1" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField2" style="padding-left:50px">Label2:</label>
        <input id="TextField2" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField3" style="padding-left:50px">Label3:</label>
        <input id="TextField3" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField4">Label4:</label>
        <input id="TextField4" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField5" style="padding-left:50px">Label5:</label>
        <input id="TextField5" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="TextField6" style="padding-left:50px">Label6:</label>
        <input id="TextField6" value="TextField"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this html tag

```
align="center"
```

center can be substituted for left or right if you want not to position them on the center

The proper way to do it is by linking your html to a CSS file and assign each div to a certain type of class in the CSS file, this helps you avoid redundancy. To do so create a css file and
link it to the html by including this in your html code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
</head>
```

And then in your mystyle.css file you would have to include something like this

```
DIV.Left{text-align:left;}
DIV.Center{text-align:center;}
DIV.Right{text-align:right;}
```

Then your html file divs would look like

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```